# How do I add a play again feature to this hangman game?

Tags: python

I want to add a play again feature to this hangman code, which will ask you to play again after you've either won or lost the match. Here's the incomplete play again code I have currently:

```
playagain = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
    if playagain == 'Y':
        word = random.choice(wordbank)
```

I have no idea where to start.

Here's my complete game code:

```
# importing wordbank
import random
from wordbankcool import wordbank

# hangman graphics
hangman_graphics = ['_',
                    '__',
                    '__\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O',
                    '__\n |\n O\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ ',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/ \ '
                    ]

# basic functions of the game
mistakes = 0
letters_guessed = []
mistakes_allowed = len(hangman_graphics)

word = random.choice(wordbank)  # selecting a random word for the user to guess

# letters user has guessed + guessed incorrectly stored in lists
letters_word = list(word)
wrong_letters = []

print()

# amount of letters the word has
print('The word has {} letters'.format(len(letters_word)))

# while loop which will run until the the number of mistakes = number of mistakes allowed
while mistakes < mistakes_allowed:
    print()
    print('Incorrect guesses: ', end='')
    for letter in wrong_letters:
        print('{}, '.format(letter), end='')
    print()
    print('Guesses left: {}'.format(mistakes_allowed - mistakes))
    letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()

# checking if the letter has been guessed before
    while letter_user in letters_guessed or letter_user in wrong_letters:
        print()
        print('You have already guessed this letter, guess a different one.')
        letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ')

# increasing amount of mistakes if the letter that has been guessed is not in the word
    if letter_user not in letters_word:
        mistakes += 1
        wrong_letters.append(letter_user)

    print()

 # showing how many letters the user has/has not guessed
    print('Word: ', end='')

# if letter is in word, its added to letters guessed
    for letter in letters_word:
        if letter_user == letter:
            letters_guessed.append(letter_user)

# replace letters that haven't been guessed with an underscore
    for letter in letters_word:
        if letter in letters_guessed:
            print(letter + ' ', end='')
        else:
            print('_ ', end='')

    print()

# hangman graphics correlate with amount of mistakes made
    if mistakes:
        print(hangman_graphics[mistakes - 1])
    print()
    print('-------------------------------------------')  # seperator

# ending: user wins
    if len(letters_guessed) == len(letters_word):
        print()
        print(f'You won! The word was {word}!')
        print()
        playagain = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
        if playagain == 'Y':
            word = random.choice(wordbank)

# ending: user loses
if mistakes == mistakes_allowed:
    print()
    print('Unlucky, better luck next time!')
    print()
    print(f'The word was {word}.')
    print()
    playagain = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
    if playagain == 'Y':
        word = random.choice(wordbank)
```

Comment: Wrap the whole game (aside from the play again prompt) in a function; call the function in a 
`while True` loop with the prompt at the end; break out of the while loop if the user doesn't want to play anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code inside a `While` loop and check on whether he wants to play again whether he wins or loses.

```py
While playagain == 'Y':
   ...
   add a break after he wins
```

```py
# importing wordbank
import random
from wordbankcool import wordbank


# hangman graphics
hangman_graphics = ['_',
                    '__',
                    '__\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O',
                    '__\n |\n O\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ ',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/ \ '
                    ]
playagain = 'Y'
while playagain == 'Y':
    # basic functions of the game
    mistakes = 0
    letters_guessed = []
    mistakes_allowed = len(hangman_graphics)

    word = random.choice(wordbank)  # selecting a random word for the user to guess

    # letters user has guessed + guessed incorrectly stored in lists
    letters_word = list(word)
    wrong_letters = []

    print()

    # amount of letters the word has
    print('The word has {} letters'.format(len(letters_word)))

    # while loop which will run until the the number of mistakes = number of mistakes allowed
    while mistakes < mistakes_allowed:
        print()
        print('Incorrect guesses: ', end='')
        for letter in wrong_letters:
            print('{}, '.format(letter), end='')
        print()
        print('Guesses left: {}'.format(mistakes_allowed - mistakes))
        letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()

    # checking if the letter has been guessed before
        while letter_user in letters_guessed or letter_user in wrong_letters:
            print()
            print('You have already guessed this letter, guess a different one.')
            letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ')

    # increasing amount of mistakes if the letter that has been guessed is not in the word
        if letter_user not in letters_word:
            mistakes += 1
            wrong_letters.append(letter_user)

        print()

    # showing how many letters the user has/has not guessed
        print('Word: ', end='')

    # if letter is in word, its added to letters guessed
        for letter in letters_word:
            if letter_user == letter:
                letters_guessed.append(letter_user)

    # replace letters that haven't been guessed with an underscore
        for letter in letters_word:
            if letter in letters_guessed:
                print(letter + ' ', end='')
            else:
                print('_ ', end='')

        print()

    # hangman graphics correlate with amount of mistakes made
        if mistakes:
            print(hangman_graphics[mistakes - 1])
        print()
        print('-------------------------------------------')  # seperator

    # ending: user wins
        if len(letters_guessed) == len(letters_word):
            print()
            print(f'You won! The word was {word}!')
            print()
            playagain = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
            if playagain == 'Y':
                word = random.choice(wordbank)
            break

    # ending: user loses
    if mistakes == mistakes_allowed:
        print()
        print('Unlucky, better luck next time!')
        print()
        print(f'The word was {word}.')
        print()
        playagain = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
        if playagain == 'Y':
            word = random.choice(wordbank)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable before all of the game logic occurs named for example playagain which will recevie a boolean value (at first true)
`playagain = True`, and put all of the game logic inside a while loop that checks if playagain equals to true.

```
while (playagain):
  # Game Logic


  # Then at the end of the game logic but still inside the while 
  # loop ask the user if he wants to continue to play

 keepPlaying = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
 if keepPlaying != 'Y':
    playagain = False
```